# Is there any way to convert a wordpress site in to a react native app

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I would like to convert my wordpress site in to an android app using react native, is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can convert but here is more better way to create native app via WP-API : https://deliciousbrains.com/creating-mobile-app-wp-api-react-native/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can create the front end in React Native and use the Wordpress API to feed your content to the front end.